# Ruby Mechanize Zlib::BufError

Tags: ruby, mechanize

Not sure why I'm getting this error now with the Mechanize gem - been using it for a while now with no issues.

My script will randomly stop and throw the following error:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:798:in `rescue in response_content_encoding': error handling content-encoding gzip: buffer error (Zlib::BufError) (Mechanize::Error)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think we need to know where you're receiving your data, so give us a URL. We also need to see the code that handles that request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that you're hitting a URL that points to a load-balancer. One of the hosts behind that load-balancer is mis-configured, or perhaps it's configured *differently* than its peers, and is returning a gzipped version of the content, where others aren't. I've seen that problem in the past.

I've also see situations where the server *said* it was returning gzipped content, but sent it uncompressed. Or it could be sending zipped, not gzipped. The combinations are many.

The fix is to be sure your code is capable of sensing whether the returned content is compressed. Make sure you're sending the correct acceptable-content HTTP headers for your code to their server too. You have to program defensively and look at the actual content you get back, and then branch to do the right decompression, then pass that on for parsing.

Comment: This is helpful - thank you. I'm basically creating a bot/crawler that creates a session on a site, and does certain actions on behalf of the logged in user. Most of my requests are POST using Mechanize, but it looks like the error is with one of the GET requests. Perhaps I will declare the headers explicitly as opposed to just using `a.get` and see how it goes.

Comment: You need to define the headers. Without them you are at the whim of the developers of that system. With them, well, at least you did the right thing.

Comment: Glad it helped. Use this new-found power for good, not evil. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get around this by setting the request headers like the following:

`mechanize.request_headers = { "Accept-Encoding" => "" }`

Comment: That fixed for me too, although I have no idea why