# `finish': buffer error (Zlib::BufError) while web scraping with ruby and mechanize

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I'm scraping multiple pages (from an array) and checking links on those pages. Every once in a while the script will crash and I will git the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb:357:in `finish': buffer error (Zlib::BufError)
```

> I found a answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18243426/ruby-mechanize-zlibbuferror) that says: It's possible that you're
>   hitting a URL that points to a load-balancer. One of the hosts behind
>   that load-balancer is mis-configured, or perhaps it's configured
>   differently than its peers, and is returning a gzipped version of the
>   content, where others aren't. I've seen that problem in the past.
>
> I've also see situations where the server said it was returning
>   gzipped content, but sent it uncompressed. Or it could be sending
>   zipped, not gzipped. The combinations are many.
>
> The fix is to be sure your code is capable of sensing whether the
>   returned content is compressed. Make sure you're sending the correct
>   acceptable-content HTTP headers for your code to their server too. You
>   have to program defensively and look at the actual content you get
>   back, and then branch to do the right decompression, then pass that on
>   for parsing

I really don't understand it. I just want to be able to skip the the element in the array and move on to the next one. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Add a `rescue` block?

Comment: Yeah. That did it. I"m new to programming. :(